# How do I change the resolution in MoH:AA?

Tags: medal-of-honor

trying to change MoH:AA's resolution to 1366x768 but that option isn't available in the game options menu. Can't find the right .cfg file to edit it manually either. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I'll also be needing to edit MoH:AA:Spearhead and MoH:AA:Breakthrough's resolutions as well, so that would also be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be available?

Answer (score 1):

There is a config fix that allows you to edit a cfg filed called "unnamedsoldier.cfg".  The lines you need to change are:

> seta r_customwidth "1920" //Adjust to your custom width.
>
> seta r_customheight "1280" //Adjust to your custom height
>
> seta r_mode "-1" //This locks the custom resolution in the game.

That said, it will not work with the expansions.  They simply don't support the system, they don't create the proper configs to edit and they don't read the same config that the core game does.  Also, in order for the game to even generate the proper config file to begin with you need to install Allied Assault by itself first.

Comment: MY unnamedsoldier.cfg file doesn't contain these lines. Should i add them? If so, where should i add them? Anywhere in the .cfg?

Comment: Go ahead and add them, just stick them in there anywhere. As long as they are on their own lines they should execute.

Comment: each expansion should have its own subfolder (such as `mainta`) from which the config file for the expansion is loaded.